# Rearrange the title, the thumbnail, and the content in a theme template

Tags: posts

In `pages-news.php`

```
<div class="thirteen columns"><?php 
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
  the_post_thumbnail();}  ?>
  <div class="title-blog">
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?> </a></h2>
</div><?php 
if( in_array( $post->ID, array() )) {
  echo get_the_content();
} else {
  echo get_excerpt();
}?>
</div>
```

In `single-page-news.php`

```
<div class="thirteen columns">
  <div class="title-single"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2> </div>
  <?php the_content();?>
</div>
```

The `pages-news.php` is what I want but the `single-page-news.php` is wrong. For the single page of article, at first I want `the_post_thumbnail`, after that the title of article, and then the content. How can I do that?

Comment: Move code from former to latter?..

Comment: The result is the same. <?php the_content();?> has the_post_thumbnail.

Comment: what theme is that?  `the_content()` does normally not show the featured image.

Answer (score 0):

This seems too simple. I am afraid that I have badly misunderstood something. Apologies if that is the case.

Alter `single-page-news.php` to be...

```
<div class="thirteen columns"><?php
  the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
  <div class="title-single">
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
  </div><?php
  the_content(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I do that. For this i have : post_thumbnail->title -> post_thubnail-> text

Comment: The `the_post_thumbnail` only shows up once in that code. Do you have a filter on `the_content` that might be duplicating it? Comment out the `the_content()` line and see what happens.

Comment: No i don't have any filter. When i comment out the `the_content()` show only the title and post_thubnails

Comment: Here you seem to say that `the_content` does not print the post thumbnail but above you say that `the_content` prints the post thumbnail, which is not normal and means you probably do have a filter. It is _very, very, very_ hard to work out what you mean. Do you mean thumbnails with at 's'-- more than one?

Comment: Tragic mistake. I am unjustifiable. When upload an image, in addition to the featured image i put this into the post. Consequently duplicated images.

Comment: I thought it was something like that.